# Show EMR stdout logs in console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

How can I make stdout logs appear in the EMR Step tabs. The logs are in the S3 bucket but only the stdout won't show.

[image: EMR Steps Logs]

Comment: Same here, syslog* and stdout* always have been unactive.